# Lower bound on the rank of a graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, graph-theory

[This has been edited in response to comments from Fedor Petrov]

Suppose that $n=dm$ with $d,m>1$.  Consider an $n\times n$ matrix $M$ such that

1. All diagonal entries are equal to one
2. Each row has $d$ ones, and all other entries are zero.

This can be seen as the adjacency matrix of a certain kind of directed graph; I am not sure whether that perspective is useful or not.  Anyway, I will consider $M$ as a matrix over a finite field $\mathbb{Z}/p$, and I would like to prove that the rank is at least $m$ (which is achieved in the case where $M=J_d\oplus\dotsb\oplus J_d$ and $J_d$ is the all  one matrix ).  Random experiments (with $m,d\leq 4$ and $p\in\{3,5,7\}$ and $\sim 10^5$ samples) suggests that the rank is always at least $m(d-1)$ with very high probability, but the above example shows that this is not always true.  Does anyone know a proof that the rank is always at least $m$?

Comment: This is too good to be true, consider the matrix composed of all-1 blocks of size $d\times d$

Comment: @FedorPetrov indeed you are right, so I revert to the question of proving that the rank is at least $m$, which is actually what I originally wanted to ask.  I will edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$m$ is a tight bound.

If the matrix be composed of $m$ blocks $d\times d$ with all 1's, its rank equals $m$.

For any $M$ satisfying your conditions, you may color $\{1, 2,\ldots,n\}$ in $d$ colors so that $M_{i, j}=0$ for all $i<j$ of the same color (if $1, 2,\ldots,k-1$ are already colored, you may choose an appropriate color for $k$, since there exist at most $d-1$ forbidden colors). Then there exist $m$ numbers of the same color, and corresponding rows and columns form a unitriangular minor, thus rank of $M$ is not less than $m$.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a greedy algorithm?  I see a one in the $(1,1)$ slot, so I greedily choose to include that in my minor, but I could have ones everywhere in the first column, and then I would be stuck.

Comment: I assume Fedor meant the following: first pick some row $R_1$. Then pick a row $R_2$ with no $1$'s in the same column as a $1$ in $R_1$. Then pick $R_3$ with no $1$'s in the same column as a $1$ in $R_1$ or $R_2$. Continuing, we obtain linearly independent rows $R_1,\dots,R_m$.

Comment: @RichardStanley but that does not work if the first column is all ones

Comment: Consider only left-to-right edges (the vertices are numbers from 1 to $n$) in your graph. I claim that you have a subset of vertices of size $m$ without such edges. Indeed, add vertices one by one. If currently you have less than $m$ vertices, there exists a vertex to which there is no arc from the already chosen vertices. Choose such a vertex $v$ with minimal $v$. Then this $v$ is on right to the already chosen vertices, so there are still no edges between choose vertices. So you get $m$ vertices without edges.

Answer (score 0):

This could be proven as follows (if i understood).
Given a complex block matrix $M\in\mathbb{M}_m(\mathbb{M}_d)$ of dimension $n$ as $d\times m=n$. Assume that all diagonal entries of $M$ are not zero and each row has at most $d$ non zero entries. We have $m\le \text{rank}(M)\le n$.
The upper bound is trivial, the lower one is also simple: (basic)
For any given matrix of rank $r$ with columns $C_1,\ldots,C_j$, adding one  column $C_0$ to $M$ increases the rank by one if and only if $C_0$ is not a linear combination of $C_i$, $1\le i\le j$.
For the $M$ defined, considering the first row; delete $d$ columns including the ones with  a non zero first entry and delete their corresponding (same) $d$ rows. Call the extracted $(m-1)\times d$ matrix: $M_1$. Clearly for this pack of $d$ columns one of them is linearly independent of the columns of $M_1$ and $\text{rank}(M)\ge \text{rank}(M_1)+1$.
Repeating the same process (this is possible because  no  zeros are  diagonal entries) to $M_1$, $m$ times, gives the bound $m$.